# Finding the Big O of psuedocode

Tags: big-o

Here's the code:

```
y = 0
for j=0 to n:
  for k=0 to (j*n):
     y+=2
```

My logic is that the inner for loop will have this summation given the known solution of sum of i from 0 to n which n(n+1)/2:

```
(j*n)(j*n + 1)/2 #in this case, j*n is what we're summing to
```

Then, this inner loop would be looped from j=0 to n, which by that logic allows me to sum that from 0 to n:

```
( (n(n+1)/2) * n)((n(n+1)/2) * n + 1) / 2
```

Where I subbed j for (n(n+1)/2). After doing the multiplications I end up with

```
O(n^6)
```

I can't tell if my logic is sound or if I'm missing something because that number seems big. Thanks.

Comment: seems more like O(n³ )

Comment: @willystyle: Good eye. In my answer, I show that it is actually pretty simple to count the actual number of iterations, no need to approximate it using Bachmann-Landau notation, and the exact number is (n³ - n²) / 2 evaluations of the `y += 2` statement. We can argue that this is three operations (get current value, add 2, write back new value), so the total number of operations is 1.5 * (n³ - n²), and the final value of `y` is n³ - n².

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make a back of the envelope calculation.

`j` is ranging from `0` to `n`. So, the highest number for `j` is `n`. That is the absolute worst case for the inner loop.

So, the absolute worst case for the inner loop is if `j == n`, in which case the loop has `j * n == n * n == n²` iterations.

Meaning, the inner loop will in the absolute worst case have `n²` iterations. The outer loop, in turn, has `n` iterations, which means that our over-estimated, absolute worst-case upper bound is `O(n³)`. It can't be worse than that. In fact, we have over-estimated by assuming that `j * n == n²`, so we know it must definitely be less than `n³`.

Now, we can try to find an even more exact bound. In fact, we can *actually* find an exact number of iterations, we don't even need Bachmann-Landau notation.

Under the assumption that the loop bounds are exclusive, the statement in the inner loop will be executed `(n³ - n²) / 2` times, and `y` will be `n³ - n²`. (Says Wolfram Alpha.)

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me understand the problem/solution.